# Prove by induction that the integral exists

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, induction, solution-verification

Let $I_n(x)=\int^x_0\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^n}dt$ for $x>0$ and $n=1,2...$

I  manipulated with the integral a bit and got the recursion: $I_{n+1}(x)=\frac{x}{2n(1+x^2)^n}+\frac{2n-1}{2n}I_n(x)$

I now need to prove that $I_n(\infty)=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{1}{(1+t^n)^n}dt=\lim_{x\to\infty}I_n(x)$ exists for all $n=1,2,...$

I prove it by induction:

Base case:

$I_1(\infty)=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\arctan\Big|^\infty_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$

So it is true for base case. Now, I assume that it's true for the $n$'th case. I try to prove that it's true for the $n+1$'th case.

$$I_{n+1}(\infty)=\frac{x}{2n(1+x^2)^n}\Big|^{\infty}_0+\frac{2n-1}{2n}I_n(\infty)=\frac{2n-1}{2n}I_n(\infty)$$

Since $I_n(\infty)$ exists, $I_{n+1}(\infty)$ exists.

Is this correct?

Comment: Is $\frac1{(1+t^2)^{n+1}}\le \frac1{(1+t^2)^{n}}$ not sufficient?

Comment: @user i think yes. This means the sequence is decreasing and bounded below so hence it converges?

Comment: They're all bounded above by $1/(1+t^2)$ and tend to $0$ pointwise. Time for the DCT if you know it.

Comment: @zhw. i see they're bounded and i don't know the DCT, but isn't my method correct?

Comment: I don't know, I wouldn't do it that way. I would go with what @user suggested. So the limit exists, yes. (The DCT tells you the limit is $0.$)